# Browse for and get path for image then have selection loaded into text box in Access form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm using HansUp's code:

```
Private Sub Command7_Click()
    Dim f As Object
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strFolder As String
    Dim varItem As Variant

    Set f = Application.FileDialog(3)
    f.AllowMultiSelect = True
    If f.Show Then
        For Each varItem In f.SelectedItems
            strFile = Dir(varItem)
            strFolder = Left(varItem, Len(varItem) - Len(strFile))
            MsgBox "Folder: " & strFolder & vbCrLf & _
                "File: " & strFile
        Next
    End If
    Set f = Nothing
End Sub
```

However, I would like the absolute path of my selection to be put into a text box instead of in a pop up window.

I'm learning as I go.

Comment: I don't remember that code, but I don't think it's appropriate for your purpose.  I think you want the user to select only one file, so should use `f.AllowMultiSelect = False`.  And you wouldn't need a `For Each` loop.  `f.SelectedItems(1)` will give you the full path of the file the user selected.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Hansup. I think the post I got the code from was years ago, I have it in my bookmarks if you need it. You are correct with only 1 file needs to be selected and I've made the change as you've advised. Removing the "for each loop...." required me to remove the "next" as well. but I got an error (run-time error '438': object doesn't support this property or method) so I put everything back. I can still get the full path in a new pop up window, but I want to get the path into a text box because my image box uses that to get the image to show in my form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't understand why you got error 438, so just wrote and tested this version.

My command button is named *cmdBrowse* and the text box where I store the selected file path is named *MyTextBox*.

```vb
Private Sub cmdBrowse_Click()
    Const msoFileDialogFilePicker As Long = 3
    Dim f As Object

    Set f = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    f.AllowMultiSelect = False
    If f.Show Then
        MsgBox f.SelectedItems(1)
        'Me!MyTextBox.Value = f.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
    Set f = Nothing
End Sub
```

After you verify the `MsgBox` shows you the file path correctly, disable that line and enable the next:

```vb
'MsgBox f.SelectedItems(1)
Me!MyTextBox.Value = f.SelectedItems(1)
```

Comment: My thoughts on that error would be this line `strFile = Dir(varItem)` the `varItem` never actually became an item since the for loop was removed.  So he was attempting to access the property on a blank variant.  Never tested this theory though.

Comment: That assignment gives me a type mismatch error when `varItem` is an empty variant.  Whatever the cause of his error, it's clear I didn't provide enough detail in the comment.  Hopefully this answer gives him everything he needs.

Comment: HansUp: Thank you so much for your help. Your new code works like a charm!!!
Newd: Thanks for your input.

Comment: @Ray glad to see you got it all up and working!  Don't forget to accept the answer :-)

Comment: @Newd: Thanks for the heads up :-)

I have a new issue, would you guys mind taking a crack at it? It's here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30519876/need-to-find-a-record-by-supplying-the-field-and-text Thanks.