# Need to find a record by supplying the field and text

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Would greatly appreciate some help with this, pls. Here's my table:

```
My_ID  | YayMi | Veer1 | Panther | 
-------+-------+-------+-------+-
1.jpg  |8542888|1256934| 758692  |
2.jpg  |698874 |8452360| 4356800 |
```

I've made a form where I have a drop down list of the "shops" and a text field to enter the file ID that they use identify my file. Then clicking the button will search my table using the entry in the drop down box plus the entry in the file number textbox to show My_ID associated with. For example, I select Panther in the drop down list, then enter 4356800 in the File ID field, click the button and I get 2.jpg as the result.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please give an example with actual data?

Comment: Having a look at your table, it really needs some database design changes. You need to have rows for shops over columns

Comment: Hi PaulFrancis, Thanks for having a look at my issue. I was thinking/researching swapping column and rows but then I couldn't reason out why it would be necessary. My habit is to put the 'finite' things in columns and things that increase goes into rows. This particular table has 16 columns and over a thousand rows and counting. Insight please?

Comment: It is necessary because that is when cascading comboxes work the best. Not just that, data retrieval, query efficiency everything will fall in place. Currently you are querying the table against itself. So I would suggest you look into normalizing your table, then post a question if you are still stuck. Right now, your only go is a DLookup statement. Something like, `DLookup("My_ID", "yourTableName", "Panther = " & Me.yourTextBoxName)`

Comment: Thanks again, PaulFrancis, for your advice. I couldn't get the DLookup statement to work, something about a syntax/compile error. I read up about cascading combo boxes and rowsources and stuff. I think I'll have to go that way in the future. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. For now tho, I went back to doing it the only way I know, I made a form with 15 buttons and accompanying queries. Not as "pretty" as I want, but it works good enough for now. I'll fix that and all the other stuff as I accumulate the knowledge and know how, lol. Thanks again for your advice.